# If i just have the .java files, whats the best way to make a project with them?

Tags: java

Using Android Studio, for some reason, I can no longer debug my program.
I tried a bunch of stuff and I made it worse.

To make a long story short I'd rather start from scratch and just copy the .java files and folder structure from the old project to a new project.
Is this practical?

I'm am familiar with modifying the manifest to add the various activities, which I can copy and paste from the old project.
Will this work?

I guess what I'm asking is: if I just have the .java files, what's the best way to make a project with them?

Comment: You're better of reading some documentation for your particular IDE regarding how project layout etc works. Netbeans is an alternative IDE (that I'm not a huge fan of, I'd advise you to stay with android studio if you want to build android apps); Maven is not an IDE but a build system; It basically lets you describe how your project should be built independent of what IDE (or even, if an IDE) being used. Think Makefiles, Ant or Gradle if you ever heard of any of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using any IDE like Eclipse, just create a new java project, add the java files in the src folder. Put all the dependencies in the classpath. The project will run fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simply ... Use [maven](http://maven.apache.org). It provides you a good layout, community support, and support in a choice of IDE.

Comment: So you guys are saying not to use Android Studio?  Instead use netbeans or maven?

Comment: Ok, I didn't have any idea you wanted to use that for developing for Android. Please consider updating your Question, and add appropriate additional tags. I don't know much about the subject if Android is the target. Take a look at http://nbandroid.org if you want to play with netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use netbeans . it gives easy way to create desktop applications